# My friend and his six roomies

Tags: riddle

I got a letter the other day from my friend, who wanted me to meet his roommates. Here's how it read:

> Hey pal!
>   
>   When are you going to come by to meet my roommates? Here's a little bit about them:
>   
>   #1 - You don't often see her outside the house, probably because she's always sleeping!
>   #2 - He can sometimes be blue, but he's a 10 in my book!
>   #3 - A well-rounded fellow, even though he kind of looks like a loser...
>   #4 - The fraternal twin brother of #2, though by looking at him, you'd think they were complete opposites.
>   #5 - I think she was a model back in the day. She's well-balanced and an excellent golfer!
>   #6 - She sounds a lot like her sister (#1) but is much more popular than her.
>   
>   Please drop in anytime (as long as it's not too crowded). We could always use another like me around here. You know where we live, right?
>   
>   Your friend,
>   [REDACTED]

The thing is, I don't know where they live, and I'm a little too shy to ask. However, I think if I figure out who they are, I might have a good idea of where I could find them. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Building on Deusovi's answer, your friend and his roommates are all

> Tetrominos.
>  The roommates are the Z-, J-, O-, L-, T-, and S-blocks, which would make your friend the I-block. Everyone is happy when one of them is dropping in, as long as there is room for them.
>
>  [image]

So, you should visit them by

> playing a few rounds of Tetris.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XteR3.gif

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that!

Comment: Good eye! Well done :) I hope you noticed the other clues in the text after the roommate descriptions.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you had mentioned them. Good job.

Answer (score 25):

These are all

> letters:

#1

> Z: Z is a rare letter,and "zzz" represents sleep

#2

> J: blue jays, and J is the tenth letter

#3

> O: round, looks like a "zero"

#4

> I or L? I and J used to be the same letter, and L is the mirror image of J (roughly)

#5

> T: symmetric, tees are used in golf, and there was a car called the "Model T" (thanks, Will)

#6:

> S is much more common than Z but it sounds nearly the same (apart from voicedness)

Comment: Also "Model [#5]"

Comment: @Will: Added it in!

Comment: Absolutely correct. Also, note that "I" wrote the letter. (In first person narrative, the author is I)

Comment: Also, your second guess for #4 is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the return address on the letter.

Comment: Way to think outside the envelope.